# jTable Plugin with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages, pageload, jquery-jtable

I'm using jTable plugin in a ASP.Net Web application. Data was loading and refreshing fine until i included the the master page file on that page. The div containing the jTable is inside an asp update panel.
I also have a jquery datepicker inside the update panel.
Neither the two divs are loading when the page loads.

i've done what is mentioned in this article, but no joy...
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601683/Working-with-jQuery-within-the-ASP-NET-UpdatePanel

The master page theme etc have also gotten messed up. Not sure if its a css issue or jQuery issue. any help in this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any errors (perhaps in your console?) those would be very usefull to debug the problem.

Comment: yes. 4 of them. unable to load some scripts/resources that have been included on the master page.

Comment: one of them is for the datepicker that i'm using. 4. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined 
 DPGlobal.parseDate bootstrap-datepicker.js:380 
 Datepicker.update bootstrap-datepicker.js:154 
 Datepicker  bootstrap-datepicker.js:82 
 (anonymous function) bootstrap-datepicker.js:330 
 st.extend.each  jquery-1.9.0.js:642 
 st.fn.st.each  jquery-1.9.0.js:263 
 $.fn.datepicker  bootstrap-datepicker.js:325 
 docReady  TimeSheet.aspx:373 
 f   jquery-1.9.0.js:1026 
 p.fireWith  jquery-1.9.0.js:1138 
 st.extend.ready  jquery-1.9.0.js:427 
 xt   jquery-1.9.0.js:97